# Word/expression for the feeling you get when you look at someone you love?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

Is there a specific word/phrase  I can use for the feeling one would get when they look at someone they love ? For example:

*Every morning when she entered the classroom, my heart would start beating faster. A feeling of ___ would rush through my veins.*

I'm not sure if the word **euphoria** would be the best word here or not, hence I'm asking this question. I'm looking for a word that is in the context of *the feeling of love* towards someone, not just excitement in general.

Comment: A lot of poets and songwriters have been looking for this answer for a long time.  If I were you, I would use figurative language to express the emotion, rather than a noun or an adjective.

Comment: gratitude would be a nice thing to feel - grateful that you had them as part of your life.   But really you could feel lots of different things. ... from awed, to charmed

Comment: Can you elaborate on the kind of love?  A secret crush?  An unrequited love?  A deep, mutual devotion?  The thrilling start of a new romance?

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime A secret crush

Comment: Euphoria is a great word for this feeling.  But I'm not sure it rushes through your veins.  How about "I would be filled with euphoria"?

Comment: "*the feeling of love*" is complex. It is not one feeling. And the feeling that someone has when looking at someone they love could be any feeling at all. Too broad/unclear, and opinion-based.

Comment: Whenever I saw her face, [oxytocin](http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/275795.php) would literally rush in my brian... No? Not romantic-sounding? But it would be accurate :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Psychologists use:

> [Limerence](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/limerence) /ˈlɪməɹəns/ Noun
>
> state of mind caused by a romantic attraction; or
>
> An involuntary romantic infatuation with another person, especially combined with an overwhelming, obsessive need to have one's feelings reciprocated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

> ***[gratitude](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gratitude)***
>   ˈɡradəˌt(y)o͞od/
>   noun
>
> the quality of being thankful; readiness to show appreciation for and to return kindness.